# Spock mock never seems to get called when called in gpars activeobject method

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock, gpars, active-objects

In my code I have two classes, one a thing called DynamicRule, and the other a wrapper for this called AORule which provides a GPARS activeObject wrapper for a rule instance.

The DynamicRule looks a bit like this - with a method called dynamicExecute

```
@InheritConstructors
@Component
@Slf4j  //use Groovy AST to get logger
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Scope ("prototype")       //IOC to deliver new instance on each injection
@Qualifier ("dynamicRule")

class DynamicRule extends BasicRule implements org.easyrules.api.Rule {

    Closure dynamicEvaluation = null
    Closure dynamicExecution = null
    String  sync = "sync"
... with method 
void dynamicExecute () {
    log.debug "dynamic execute: " + this.dump() +  " : dynamic execute called : a rule.dynamicExecution was defined as > " + this.dynamicExecution
    //if dynamic execution closure defined then call that
    log.debug "dynamic execute: getting DynamicExecution reference "
    def clos = this.getDynamicExecution()
    //assert clos == this.dynamicExecution
    log.debug "dynamic execute: rule.dynamicExecution using get() returns " + clos.dump()
    if (clos) {
        clos.call()  //call execute action
        log.debug "dynamic execute: dynamic rule closure  was executed "
    }
}....
```

I have a wrapper class for this AORule that's using GPARS activeObject to manage the state of `DynamicRule rule` reference like this, where the `execute()` method calls the async activeObject method to trigger the action on the internal `rule` reference

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@ActiveObject
@Slf4j
@EqualsAndHashCode
class AORule implements org.easyrules.api.Rule {

    //setup delegate dynamicRule and make it a part of this ActiveObject
    //prototyped setter injection
    //@Autowired
    //@Scope ("prototype")
    //@Qualifier ("dynamicRule")
    @Delegate DynamicRule rule

    AORule (name, description=null) {
        log.debug "Create aorule.rule name/desc constructor called "
        rule = new DynamicRule (name, description ?: "Basic Active Object Rule")
    }

    AORule () {
        log.debug "Create aorule.rule default constructor called "
        rule = new DynamicRule ()
    }

    @Autowired (/*required=true*/)
    AORule (@Qualifier ("dynamicRule") DynamicRule dynrule) {
        log.debug "Create aorule.rule injected rule constructor called "
        rule = dynrule
    }
    ....
   void execute () {
        active_execute()
    }

    /**
     * Active method manages async action through object inside through hidden actor.
     * variable 'rule' is the variable we are protecting.  Runs either any dynmicExecution closure
     * where defined or just runs the standard class execute method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    @ActiveMethod
    void active_execute () {
        //rule.execute()

        log.debug "activeExec : rule dump looks like   " + rule.dump()

        def val = rule.dynamicExecution
        assert val == true

        log.debug "activeExec : ret value of rule.getDynamicExecution() was > " + val

        if (val != null) {
            log.debug "activeExec : running dynamicExecution closure, where rule closure was " + rule?.dynamicExecution.toString()
            rule.dynamicExecute()  //should call method that executes closure, where this is defined
        }
        else {
            log.debug "activeExec : running std Execution action  "
            rule.execute()

        }

    }
```

I have been trying to write some tests to show this is working to myself and it fails.  I've tried to do two simple tests one for dynamicRule by itself which works - I setup the expectation and ask the Mock to call a closure and test the side effect of that closure on the `mockres` variable - all works ok as expected:

```
def "set execution closure using spock mock  but call stub directly  when doing an execute action " () {

    given:"setup of stub for testing "

    def mockres = ""

    def clos = {
        mockres = "did nothing";
        println "script: in stub closure, setting mockres to  " + mockres + " mockres dump > " + mockres.dump();
    }

    //spock mock
    DynamicRule stub =  Mock  ()
    1*stub.dynamicExecute() >> {clos()}  // pretend this has been set


    when : "execution on stub directly  "

    stub.dynamicExecute()

    then : "test execute closure ran as expected "
    mockres == "did nothing"

}
```

In my second test I set up the Mock and set it on the aorule.rule instance and set the expectation for the mock, call the `aorule.execute()` method which invokes the `activeExecute()` active method, which calls my mock

```
def "set execution closure using spock mock  but call aorule.execute()  when doing an execute action " () {

    given:"setup of stub for testing "

    def mockres = ""

    def clos = {
        mockres = "did nothing";
        println "script: in stub closure, setting mockres to  " + mockres + " mockres dump > " + mockres.dump();
    }

    //spock mock
    DynamicRule stub =  Mock  ()
    1*stub.getDynamicExecution() >> { true }
    1*stub.dynamicExecute() >> {clos()}  // pretend this has been set

    println "test: save stub on aorule"
    aorule.rule = stub

    when : "call execute() on aorule.rule for stub   "

    //stub.dynamicExecute()
    //aorule.rule.dynamicExecute()  //works
    println "test: call aorule.execute"
    aorule.execute()   //think this must be getting a new prototype object which is why not getting called

    then : "test execute closure ran as expected "
    mockres == "did nothing"

}
```

This fails - why closure is not run on the mock and the then: assertion test fails.

I've included part of the output trace here - you can see that `aorule.execute()` triggers the activeObject method, and I can see the log trace for the `activeExec : rule dump looks like`  - however after that it all seems to stop, no extra trace output (I was expecting to see value of val for example), and the stub closure IS NOT called and mockres does not get set - test fails

```
...
test: save stub on aorule
13:07:45.361 [main] DEBUG org.easyrules.spring.AORule - setting aorule.rule with > Mock for type 'DynamicRule' named 'stub'
test: call aorule.execute
13:07:45.367 [Actor Thread 1] DEBUG org.easyrules.spring.AORule - activeExec : rule dump looks like   <org.easyrules.spring.DynamicRule$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$9b33215e@a4770a4 CGLIB$BOUND=false CGLIB$CALLBACK_0=org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CglibMockInterceptorAdapter@4809f9c CGLIB$CALLBACK_1=net.sf.cglib.proxy.NoOp$1@bf1bd4 dynamicEvaluation=null dynamicExecution=null sync=null name=null description=null priority=0>
13:07:45.441 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@5c6648b0 testClass = AORuleSpecTest2, testInstance = org.easyrules.spring.AORuleSpecTest2@d41f816, testMethod = $spock_feature_0_1@AORuleSpecTest2, testException = Condition not satisfied:

mockres == "did nothing"
|       |
""      false
        11 differences (0% similarity)
        (-----------)
        (did nothing)
, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@6f1de4c7 testClass = AORuleSpecTest2, locations = '{}', classes = '{class org.easyrules.spring.AORule, class org.easyrules.spring.DynamicRule}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null], method annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].

Condition not satisfied:
```

I have been trying to trace this, or watch in debugger to no avail. My stubs closure is not triggered - test fails.

I've just tried to watch in the debugger again and when I step past the line

```
    def val = rule.dynamicExecution
```

the debugger jumps off into `InternalActor.handleCurrentMessage()` error handler somewhere in GPARs.  Makes no difference if I change this to

```
    def val = rule.getDynamicExecution()  //try to get value via groovy auo method
```

I don't understand this. Perhaps I am doing something silly, but I can't write a test for my `@ActiveMethod - activeExecute()` to test code using Mocks (I've tried to do this via hand crafted classes, etc and cannot get the simulated tests to work.

How can I correct and run the tests properly? So far as I can tell - when I run the code in scripts ('live' tests) the code appears to do what I want it to do, etc but I can't make unit test to show that

Postscript: it's to do with ActiveMethod wrapping - not sure what

I created two dummy wrapper classes in the test script as follows - one without ActiveObject and one with ActiveObject support - both call the `dynamicExecute()` method on the embedded rule.   AOWrappers is `@ActiveMethod`

```
class WrapperRule {
    @Autowired   //property injection
    @Delegate DynamicRule rule

    WrapperRule () {

    }

    WrapperRule (DynamicRule irule) {
        rule = irule
        assert rule
    }

    void execute () {
        rule.dynamicExecute()
    }

}

@ActiveObject
@Slf4j
@EqualsAndHashCode
class AOWrapperRule {
    @Autowired   //property injection
    @Delegate DynamicRule rule

    AOWrapperRule () {

    }

    AOWrapperRule (DynamicRule irule) {
        rule = irule
        assert rule
    }

    @ActiveMethod
    void execute () {
        rule.dynamicExecute()
    }

}
```

the two tests in same script file look this

```
def "set execution closure using spock mock  on simple Wrapper rule  when doing an execute action " () {

    given:"setup of stub for testing "

    def mockres = ""

    def clos = {
        mockres = "did nothing";
        println "script: in stub closure, setting mockres to  " + mockres + " mockres dump > " + mockres.dump();
    }

    WrapperRule wrule = new WrapperRule ()

    //spock mock
    DynamicRule stub =  Mock  ()
    1*stub.dynamicExecute() >> {clos()}  // pretend this has been set

    println "test: save stub on wrule"
    wrule.rule = stub

    when : "call execute() on wrule.rule for stub   "

    println "test: call wrule.execute"
    wrule.execute()   //think this must be getting a new prototype object which is why not getting called

    then : "test execute closure ran as expected "
    mockres == "did nothing"

}

def "set execution closure using spock mock  on AO Wrapper rule  when doing an execute action " () {

    given:"setup of stub for testing "

    def mockres = ""

    def clos = {
        mockres = "did nothing";
        println "script: in stub closure, setting mockres to  " + mockres + " mockres dump > " + mockres.dump();
    }

    AOWrapperRule aowrule = new AOWrapperRule ()

    //spock mock
    DynamicRule stub =  Mock  ()
    1*stub.dynamicExecute() >> {clos()}  // pretend this has been set

    println "test: save stub on aowrapper"
    aowrule.rule = stub

    when : "call execute() on aowrule.rule for stub   "

    println "test: call aowrule.execute"
    aowrule.execute()   //think this must be getting a new prototype object which is why not getting called

    then : "test execute closure ran as expected "
    mockres == "did nothing"

}
```

When I run the tests - the first one passes just fine, the second one fails and my `clos` is not called. What should I try next?

### Clarification to question

I have tried and dumbed this down into single groovy test file - with classes being tested and the tests in the same file so that you can hopefully see what's going on

```
package org.easyrules.spring

import groovy.mock.interceptor.StubFor
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import groovyx.gpars.activeobject.ActiveMethod
import groovyx.gpars.activeobject.ActiveObject
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.softwood.RulesApplication
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll
import spock.lang.*

/**
 * Created by William on 10/03/2016.
 */

class TestRule {
    Closure dynamicExecute = {println "default rule Execution "}

    def exec () {
        dynamicExecute()
    }
}


class TestWrapperRule {
    @Delegate TestRule rule

    TestWrapperRule () {
        rule = new TestRule()
    }

    void execute () {
        rule.exec()
    }

}

@ActiveObject
@Slf4j
@EqualsAndHashCode
class TestAOWrapperRule {
    @Delegate TestRule rule

    TestAOWrapperRule () {
        rule = new TestRule()
    }

    @ActiveMethod
    void execute () {
        rule.exec()
    }

}

class AORuleSpecAllInOneSpecTest extends Specification {

    def "test simple closure setting mockres value - basics " () {
        given:
        def mockres = ""

        def clos = {
            mockres = "did nothing";
            println "script: in stub closure, setting mockres to  " + mockres + " mockres dump > " + mockres.dump();
        }

        when:
        clos()  //call closure

        then: "test mockres was set when closure called "
        mockres == "did nothing"
    }

    def "set execution closure using spock mock  on simple Wrapper rule  when doing an execute action " () {

        given:"setup of stub for testing "

        def mockres = ""

        def clos = {
            mockres = "did nothing";
            println "script: in stub closure, setting mockres to  " + mockres + " mockres dump > " + mockres.dump();
        }

        TestWrapperRule wrule = new TestWrapperRule ()

        //spock mock
        TestRule stub =  Mock  ()
        //1*stub.exec() >> {clos()}  // pretend this has been set
        1*stub.getDynamicExecute() >> {clos()}  // pretend this has been set

        println "test: save stub on wrule"
        wrule.rule = stub

        when : "call execute() on wrule.rule for stub   "

        println "test: call wrule.execute"
        //wrule.exec()
        wrule.dynamicExecute

        then : "test execute closure ran as expected "
        mockres == "did nothing"

    }

    def "set execution closure using spock mock  on AO Wrapper rule  when doing an execute action " () {

        given:"setup of stub for testing "

        def mockres = ""

        def clos = {
            mockres = "did nothing";
            println "script: in stub closure, setting mockres to  " + mockres + " mockres dump > " + mockres.dump();
        }

        TestAOWrapperRule aowrule = new TestAOWrapperRule ()

        //spock mock
        TestRule stub =  Mock  ()
        stub.exec() >> {clos()}  // pretend this has been set

        println "test: save stub on aowrapper"
        aowrule.rule = stub

        when : "call execute() on aowrule.rule for stub   "

        println "test: call aowrule.execute"
        aowrule.execute()
        //aowrule.exec()  //if you then call the @delegate func without the activeMethod the test will work 

        then : "test execute closure ran as expected "
        mockres == "did nothing"

    }
}
```

The key point to note is the last test.  I set the expectation on the Mock to run the output the closure,  that will update the `mockres` variable, that I can assert has been set in the then: clause.

When you call the `@ActiveMethod execute()` the test will fail like this

```
...script: in stub closure, setting mockres to  did nothing mockres dump > <java.lang.String@c141192c value=did nothing hash=-1052698324>

Condition not satisfied:

mockres == "did nothing"
|       |
""      false
        11 differences (0% similarity)
        (-----------)
        (did nothing)
```

which shows that mockres was not set by the closure call.

If you uncomment the aowrule.exec() line that follows - this then calls the delegated `exec()` call directly - not using the hidden actor which the ActiveMethod uses.  When you run that next line the closure is called correctly and the mockres is set.

So the issue has something to do which trying to test that the mock works when its doing this through the hidden actor behind that `@ActiveMothod`.

I think in reality the code is doing what I expect if just run as a script (real use in code).  However I seem unable to write the test that proves the expected behaviour when the ActiveMethod  is being invoked.

Do I have to do something clever to write a spock test with Mocks for async code like GPARs - or is this something that should work but doesn't.

Comment: I added two new tests to the spock test script.   a simple wrapper for dynamicRule and one with ActiveObject (GPARS) support.  test without active objects works fine.  test with AOWrapper fails to execute correctly - dont know where to go now - is this a bug for gpars or cant i test async code like this with spock?

Comment: you should maybe try to extract a reproducible example a little smaller.. your question is very long to read and understand ;-)

Comment: Ok - i have cheated and dumbed this down so that it all the classes and the tests are in one groovy file - that way you can see the structure - and then the tests - see new addendum to question above to see this